# Sharepont alternate access mapping alternative port

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, iis, alternate-access-mapping, dns

I can access my WSS3 server via `http://sharepoint`, but not `http://sharepoint:800`, which I require. Ideally I would like both to be accessible. My guess is that there is a conflict between my mappings or between them and the IIS bindings.

What could be wrong with my configuration that is preventing access on port 800? The only way I can access it is using port 80 - either through `http://sharepoint` or `http://sharepoint.company.local`.

My alternate access mappings are configured as follows:

```
Internal URL                   Zone                  Public URL for zone
http://svr:19937               Default               http://svr:19937 
http://svr:800                 Default               http://svr:800
http://sharepoint.company.com  Internet              http://sharepoint.company.com
http://sharepoint:800          Custom                http://sharepoint:800
http://svr                     Default               http://svr
```

I realize there is no actual "mapping" here. TBH I don't know whether AAM is making any difference / is applicable to my problem.

The IIS bindings are:

```
Type      Hostname       Port        IP Address
http                     80          *
http                     800         *
```

I also tried to make it work by extending the application, but it doesn't work -  apparently `http://sharepoint:800` is already in use. I don't understand how - the site url is `http://svr:800`. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the port 800 has been whitelisted in your firewall on your Windows Server ?

You could also run netstat on the server and make sure that the port 800 is not internally used by something else, preventing thus a proper use for the web application.

Regarding your AAM is

```
> http://svr:800
```

an internal url (and thus added as so ?) (because it's added twice to the default zone)

19937 is your central administration right ?

Comment: When the port is in use, your web application in IIS won't start at all. I agree with Francois, your AAM list is confusing. Please make sure you only list the AAM mappings for the web application causing trouble. I also wonder why you would have a need for all these mappings. Usually a single URL with maybe an extend for different authentication methods would do it. I find it best practice to use as little mappings as possible, they only tend to create confusion when used in the wrong way.

Comment: It was the firewall! I used Windows FireWall With Advanced Security (catchy name) to enable the port on the inbound side. Thanks :)